# How to issue a 403 error in Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have written a controller in my application that finds an item that belongs to the user and returns it. However, when the request contains the ID of an item that does not belong to the user, my controller is returning an empty object. How can I force the application to issue a 403 error instead?

Here is a simplified of the code for the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/item")
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;
            
    @GetMapping(value="/getItem", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String getItem(@RequestParam("itemId") int itemId,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Model theModel) {
        
        // get the username from the HTTP Request
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        String theUsername = principal.getName();
        
        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Item theItem = itemService.getItem(itemId);
        
        if (theUsername.equals(theItem.getUserProfile().getUsername())) {
            theModel.addAttribute("item", theItem);
        } else {
            theModel.addAttribute("item", new Item());
        }
        
        return "json/item";
    }
}
```

P.S. Please note that the `ItemService` is only a middle layer that connects to the data layer and fetches the data to return.

P.S. I am aware that the design may not follow the best practices. Please feel free to highlight any design issues in the comments, but avoid ranting the post about them.

Comment: You need to explicitly set the http response code to 403, forbidden.

Comment: _In general_, the preferred way to do this is to put an `@PreAuthorize` expression on your controller method. You should also be injecting everything you get out of `request` as ordinary method parameters; Spring will handle all of the extraction and mapping for you.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Isn't `@PreAuthorize` a role-based annotation for authorisation? In this example, I am concerned with row-level security.

Comment: You can put _any_ expression in there you want. `hasRole('ADMIN')` is common, but you can also implement `PermissionEvaluator` and do something like `hasPermission(#itemId, 'Item', 'write')`. If your `Item`s are backed by a Spring Data repository, just say `@RequestParam("itemId") Item item` and `hasPermission(#item, 'write')` (and use `@PathVariable` for this; it's better REST design).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I realized that my current approach suffers in security. This opens the door for users to find which `Item` IDs are available in my DB by sending requests and checking if the result is `403` or `null`. Hence, I should always send `null` response in my controller regardless whether the item exists or it exists and user does not have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in couple of ways. You can set the status code in the controller class methods like this

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN)
public Response doSomething() { 
 //do some thing here and return
}
```

If this doesn't suits your requirement you can handle this in an exceptional handler method like this.

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN)
class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
  //Handle something here;
}
```

For better information follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status)

Comment: I could also simply `throw new AccessDeniedException("Unauthorised Access!");`. What would be the difference?

Comment: Its not about handling exception, for that matter its up to you how you want to do with the exception, but its more about setting the appropriate status code, i know there could be many number of solutions what i suggested is just one among many